# What does "having a confirm for someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The context:
"Thanks for your message.
Sorry for that you haven't received the item yet.
I understand you truly, but please don't worry; we will fix the problem for you smoothly.
Could you please give me your shipping address for us to have a confirm for you? Then we will give you an answer quickly. 
Looking forward to your reply.
Kind regards!"

Comment: Several things about this message suggest that the writer is not a native speaker of English.. Presumably they want to confirm that they have despatched the item to the right address.

Comment: "Get a confirm error/box" is becoming quite common in emails etc, so the attributive usage is getting more common. "Press the 'stop' button" certainly doesn't need ( or even warrant) the scare quotes nowadays. 'Came to a stop' and 'get the go' are certainly idiomatic, and 'have a confirm' models on these. However, the noun intercategorial polyseme (ie the noun usage) has not made it into Urban Dictionary yet, never mind Wiktionary.

Answer (score 2):

**The message has several grammatical mistakes, and the sentence you quote is not grammatically correct.**

"confirm" is a verb, but is being used here as a noun.

Therefore we cannot tell you definitely what the sentence means.

From context it seems reasonable that they are asking to confirm your shipping address, though this is something you probably guessed for yourself. Since the sentence is incorrect, no expert in English is going to be able to tell you accurately what it means.

Comment: I’ll give you a confirm on that :)